# Sonar runner does not import trx test result files

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I’m trying to import trx test result files into SonarQube, therefore I have added the line

```
sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=../../TestResults/*.trx
```

to the properties file. Unfortunately I cannot see any test results in Sonar. I have executed sonar-runner with the “-X -e”  option but I cannot see any useful information in the log. I have searched for "trx" and "vstest". Nothing. Can someone tell me where I can find some more information on what’s going wrong?

Here is my setup:

> sonar runner 2.4
>
> sonar server 5.1
>
> C# plugin 4.0
>
> Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects 1.2

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an absolute path to your .trx file to start with, then make it relative, then use wildcards.

I suspect that no .trx file is matching the pattern you are giving, which is why nothing is shown in the logs.

Once the .trx file is successfully located, you will see `Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file ...` appear in the logs.

Comment: It works with the full path and it works with the relative path specifying the concrete file. But it does not work with wild cards. I assume that ***.trx** would match any file which ends with **.trx**. But for some reason it does not match **128030aa-d74b-4144-ba45-c865b4c97ac8.trx**. Any ideas?

Comment: i have the same! did you find the reason?